# Multimap with key as unordered set and value as integer pair - unable to call find member function

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, unordered-set

Consider code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

typedef std::unordered_multimap<std::unordered_set<int>, std::pair<int, int>, boost::hash<std::unordered_set<int>>> user_type_mmap;
    //Essentially, above is a map, whose elements can be:
    // Key: Set {1,4} -> Value: pair (4,5)
    // Key: Set {1,4} -> Value: pair (4,8)
    // Key: Set {2,3} -> Value: pair (8,9)
typedef std::pair<std::unordered_set<int>, std::pair<int, int>> user_type_mmap_entry;
    //The above is an entry pair into the multimap

bool unorderedmultimap_val_there_already_add_if_not(user_type_mmap& uom, user_type_mmap_entry& val) {
    if (uom.find(val) != uom.end()) {
        return true;//val already there
    }
    uom.insert(val);
    return false;//Value is new.
}

int main()
{
    user_type_mmap uom;
    std::unordered_set<int> set = { 1, 4 };
    user_type_mmap_entry val = std::make_pair(set, std::pair<int, int>(4, 5));
    unorderedmultimap_val_there_already_add_if_not(uom, val);
}
```

Essentially, I define an unordered multimap whose value-key pairs are an unordered set (as key) and a pair of integers (as value).

Then, function `unorderedmultimap_val_there_already_add_if_not` checks to see if a candidate entry exists in the multimap already, and if it does not exist, add it to the multimap.

I am having difficulty compiling this (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3sqG88YzY)) since the function call `uom.find()` returns error:

`error: no matching member function for call to 'find'`.

Multimaps do support `find()` member function (see [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/)) and it is not clear to me why `uom.find(val)` fails in this case.

Comment: `find` requires an instance of the `key` type.  You're passing an `std::pair<std::unordered_set<int>, std::pair<int, int>>` rather than an `std::unordered_set<int>` as required (I think).

Comment: @G.M. Multimaps allow for multiple key entries to be the same, but disallow multiple (key, value) entries that are the same. You are probably right. See https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/find/ Hmm..Do you know if there is a built in member function that indices whether a `(key, value)` pair already exists and not just whether a `key` exists?

Comment: Looks like, I would have to manually iterate using function equal_range. See https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/equal_range/

Comment: Unrelated: Hashing a `std::unordered_set<int>` sounds expensive. Does `boost::hash<std::unordered_set<int>>` even work without additional functions? [It doesn't look like it](https://godbolt.org/z/5hcfnase1)

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are absolutely correct. Please see https://godbolt.org/z/anqoefoe6 Here, while my main.cpp does not throw any errors, boost does complain that the hash I provided does not work. Order does not really matter to me. Hence my choice of set/unordered set. Perhaps I should try a plain set instead of unordered. If that also does not work, I should possibly have to sort my set in some order and store it as a vector. I know that boost hash for std::vector<int> works fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your code. Modified that https://godbolt.org/z/4oxshqbox to confirm that hash for a set works. This should suffice for my purposes.

Comment: @Tryer You're welcome!  About: "_Multimaps allow for multiple key entries to be the same, but disallow multiple (key, value) entries that are the same_" That's not correct. You can insert multiple equal _Key_ / _Value_ pairs into a `std::unordered_multimap`.

Comment: Hmm..I interpreted the following line from CPPReference "Unordered multimaps are associative containers that store elements formed by the combination of a key value and a mapped value, much like unordered_map containers, but **allowing different elements to have equivalent keys.**" to indicate (due to omission of `values`) that keys can be the same, but for a given key, values cannot be. I am possibly wrong in my interpretation then.

Comment: @Tryer Yes, that's not correct. _"different"_ is perhaps a bit ambigous. The _Value_ elements stored for each _Key_ are different but can have the same values. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/sdM9jnKzP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others said, you're

- missing a hash implementation
- using a pretty inefficient key type

I'd simplify on both accounts:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4ren5WPqE)**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/small_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using Key   = boost::container::flat_set<int, std::less<>,
                                       boost::container::small_vector<int, 4>>;
using Value = std::pair<int, int>;

template <> struct std::hash<Key> {
    size_t operator()(Key const& s) const { return boost::hash_range(s.begin(), s.end()); }
};

using user_type_mmap       = std::unordered_multimap<Key, Value>;
using user_type_mmap_entry = user_type_mmap::value_type;

bool ensure(user_type_mmap& uom, Key key, Value val) {
    if (uom.find(key) == uom.end()) {
        uom.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val));
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main(){
    user_type_mmap uom{
        {{2, 3}, {8, 9}},
        {{3, 4}, {9, 10}},
    };

    fmt::print("1: {}\n", uom);
    fmt::print("insertion: {}\n", ensure(uom, {1, 4}, {4, 5}));
    fmt::print("2: {}\n", uom);
    fmt::print("insertion: {}\n", ensure(uom, {1, 4}, {4, 8}));
    fmt::print("3: {}\n", uom);
}
```

Prints

```
1: {({3, 4}, (9, 10)), ({2, 3}, (8, 9))}
insertion: false
2: {({1, 4}, (4, 5)), ({2, 3}, (8, 9)), ({3, 4}, (9, 10))}
insertion: true
3: {({1, 4}, (4, 5)), ({2, 3}, (8, 9)), ({3, 4}, (9, 10))}
```

This also makes the key type not use any dynamic allocation when the set is small enough.

### BONUS IDEA

It looks a bit like you're manually shoe-horning additional key restrictions into standard containers. Consider using MultiIndex:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/c7sYjr37b)**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/small_vector.hpp>

#include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Key = boost::container::flat_set<int, std::less<>,
                                    boost::container::small_vector<int, 4>>;

template <> struct boost::hash<Key> {
    size_t operator()(Key const& k) const {
        return boost::hash_range(k.begin(), k.end());
    }
};

struct Record {
    Key key;
    int a, b; // the pair

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record const& r)
    {
        fmt::format_to(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os), "{{ k:{} a:{} b:{} }}", r.key, r.a, r.b);
        return os;
    }
};

using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<
    Record,
    bmi::indexed_by< //
        //bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct byKey>,
                                //bmi::member<Record, Key, &Record::key>>,
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct byKeyHash>,
                                bmi::member<Record, Key, &Record::key>>,
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct byFull>,
            bmi::composite_key<Record, //
                            bmi::member<Record, Key, &Record::key>,
                            bmi::member<Record, int, &Record::a>,
                            bmi::member<Record, int, &Record::b> //
                            >>>>;

bool ensure(Table& uom, Key key, int a, int b) {
    return uom.insert(Record{std::move(key), a, b}).second;
}

int main(){
    Table uom{
        {{2, 3}, 8, 9},
        {{3, 4}, 9, 10},
    };

    fmt::print("1: {}\n", uom);
    fmt::print("insertion: {}\n", ensure(uom, {1, 4}, 4, 5));
    fmt::print("2: {} count {{1,4}}:{}\n", uom, uom.count(Key{1, 4}));
    fmt::print("insertion: {}\n", ensure(uom, {1, 4}, 4, 8));
    fmt::print("3: {} count {{1,4}}:{}\n", uom, uom.count(Key{1, 4}));
    fmt::print("insertion: {}\n", ensure(uom, {1, 4}, 4, 5));
    fmt::print("4: {} count {{1,4}}:{}\n", uom, uom.count(Key{1, 4}));
}
```

Prints

```
1: [{ k:[2, 3] a:8 b:9 }, { k:[3, 4] a:9 b:10 }]
insertion: true
2: [{ k:[2, 3] a:8 b:9 }, { k:[3, 4] a:9 b:10 }, { k:[1, 4] a:4 b:5 }] count {1,4}:1
insertion: true
3: [{ k:[2, 3] a:8 b:9 }, { k:[3, 4] a:9 b:10 }, { k:[1, 4] a:4 b:8 }, { k:[1, 4] a:4 b:5 }] count {1,4}:2
insertion: false
4: [{ k:[2, 3] a:8 b:9 }, { k:[3, 4] a:9 b:10 }, { k:[1, 4] a:4 b:8 }, { k:[1, 4] a:4 b:5 }] count {1,4}:2
```

Comment: @Tryer "Do you know if there is a built in member function that indices whether a (key, value) pair already exists and not just whether a key exists?" - that's multi-index territory: [Bonus Idea](https://godbolt.org/z/c7sYjr37b)

Comment: Just in case it wasn't self-explanatory, you can use the `byKey{Hash}` index to get the original behaviour back/as well: https://godbolt.org/z/3fPWebcsP

Comment: Hey sehe. Thanks, as always, for your detailed response. As always, it will take me quite a few days to digest the ideas you present.

Comment: I am trying something very simple here: https://godbolt.org/z/a3v7Ya34r
The compiler complains that `error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at <source>:12:13)'
        __f(*__first);`
Could you help with figuring out what I am doing wrong? I thought I created a lambda to compare the `val` (pair of ints) with what is already stored.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your first code example in your answer, you only check if the key exists. I would like to check whether the key/value pair exists.

Comment: I think I have been able to narrow it down: `for_each(range.first,range.second,
                [&](std::pair<int, int>& x) {if (x.first == val.first && x.second == val.second)                        return true;}` is just wrong. I thought for each's range would return an std::pair<int, int> but it seems to be returning a set.

Comment: Figured it out https://godbolt.org/z/vr4bxfsa5
Although, I still don't understand why `std::pair<std::set<int>, std::pair<int, int> > element` works, while `std::pair<std::set<int>, std::pair<int, int> >& element` does not inside the lambda.

Comment: If you want to "check whether the key/value pair exists" then the "key value pair" is the key. Use a set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240903/discussion-between-sehe-and-tryer).